# How to send result data from one page to another page in React

Tags: reactjs, forms, components

On the Calculation form, the result can display but what I want is when the user clicks on the button "Calculate saving range", it will link to another page and display the result as well. I try to send data from Calculate.js to Result.js but it does not work

My code is here: https://codesandbox.io/s/calculation-form-uxip8?file=/src/components/Calculator.jsx

On Result.jsx

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

import {NavLink } from "react-router-dom";


class Result extends Component {
    
    render(){
        return(
            <div className="result">
                <h2>You could save between</h2>
                <h1>{this.props.value}</h1>
               <NavLink to="/">Use Calculator Again</NavLink>

            </div>

        )
    }
}

export default Result
```

Anyone can stop by and give me some help. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply pass the data along with the route push/replace.

Using the Redirect component with existing implementation

```
<Redirect
  to={{
    pathname: "/result",
    state: {
      value:
        "$" +
        Math.floor(1.69 * this.state.square * (10 / 100)) +
        "- $" +
        Math.floor(1.69 * this.state.square * (30 / 100))
    }
  }}
/>
```

Since your components are being directly rendered by a `Route` component they are passed [route props](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/route-props). This means that `Calculator` has access to the `history` prop to imperatively redirect, and `Result` can access the `location` prop to get the route state.

Calculator.js

Update the submit handler to do the redirect to the "/result" route and pass along the state. Remove the `div` at the end of the return with `Result`, you don't need that on this page. Use `history.push` if you want the user to be able to go back to form.

```
handleSubmit = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  this.props.history.replace({
    pathname: "/result",
    state: {
      value:
        "Your saving range is: $" +
        Math.floor(1.69 * this.state.square * (10 / 100)) +
        "- $" +
        Math.floor(1.69 * this.state.square * (30 / 100))
    }
  });
};
```

Result.js

Just need to access the route state `props.location.state.value`.

```
class Result extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="result">
        <h2>You could save between</h2>
        <h1>{this.props.location.state.value}</h1> // <-- route state
        <NavLink to="/">Use Calculator Again</NavLink>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

## Important

Make sure your routes and app code are wrapped in a router! Swap the order of your routes so you specify more specific routes *before* less specific routes. This is so the `Switch` can try matching more specific routes first, then falling back to the less specific ones.

```
...
import { Switch, Route, BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
...

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router> // <-- need to wrap app in Router so routes work correctly
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/result" component={Result} />
          <Route path="/" component={Calculator} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit how-to-send-result-data-from-one-page-to-another-page-in-react]

Answer (score 0):

In React, when you want two components to communicate together, there must be a state in one of their common ancestors.

In your app, the common ancestor of `Calculator` and `Result` is `App` so you should have a state in `App`.

```
function App() {
  const [result,setResult] = useState(null)
  return (
    <div className="App">
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={() => <Calculator setResult={setResult}/>} />
      <Route path="/result" component={() => <Result result={result}/>} />
    </Switch>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Then, `Calculator` can call `setResult` internally to modify `result` which can then be read by `Result`.

Another option is to use Redux.